# How do I install the latest version of Chromium in Debian Squeeze?

Tags: debian, chrome

I know that Debian Squeeze has Chromium 6.x only. So I added backports but seems that Chromium is not included. Since Chromium/Chrome development is very fast, version 6.x has sort of become outdated.

Is there a way to install the latest version of Chromium to Debian Squeeze without changing the system from stable to testing/unstable?

Answer (score 5):

The preferred way to do this is to use apt pinning. It allows you to install a single package from testing/unstable, without migrating the whole system to testing/unstable. Caution: this will bring also package dependencies to testing. Pay attention at what are you doing.
A complete guide to pinning is here: http://wiki.debian.org/it/AptPreferences
What you need to do is:

Edit /etc/apt/apt.conf and add the following line (or edit a similar line if present)

```
APT::Default-Release "stable";
```

Edit /etc/apt/sources.list and add (replace the mirror with your own). You will have a similar line with stable in place of testing. DO NOT EDIT THAT LINE.

```
deb ftp://http.us.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free
```

Now edit /etc/apt/preferences, and add

```
Package: chromium-browser
Pin: release a=testing
Pin-Priority: 900
```

Run `apt-get update`; to check that you haven't switched to testing, try to launch a apt-get upgrade. If you see lots of upgrades (maybe upgrade your system just before starting the procedure), abort: something has gone wrong. You may or may not see chromium in the upgrades: if not, upgrade it with

```
apt-get install -t testing chromium-browser
```

Comment: I checked and found that there are a number of dependencies on the "`wheezy`" release of `chromium` that make it impractical to install on "`squeeze`".

Comment: Well, every way of installing latest chromium on squeeze is going to need those dependencies. So your options are to keep squeeze version of chromium, drag all those dependencies from wheezy, or entirely upgrade to wheezy. squeeze is now oldstable, and in some months jessie will be the next stable. I heard that squeeze will be mantained by non-debian people for some time, but still if you are a desktop user (and if you aren't, I think you don't care about Chromium) you should really be using the latest stable.

Comment: As of today stable has v73, testing has v73 and unstable has v75. Is it safe to follow the procedure for unstable? It suggests huge changes to the system (_91 upgraded, 41 newly installed, 12 to remove_) including system core libraries

Comment: I wouldn't do that unless v75 has something you *really* need

Comment: @p91paul Security...

Comment: Security patches are usually backported to stable, and quite fast (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/508609/how-quickly-are-debian-security-patches-moved-to-stable). So security should not be considered as a reason to switch that much packages to their unstable version, unless you are aware of a critical vulnerability in v73 not yet patched in stable.

Comment: But if the Debian package is not updated, we know that those security patches have not been applied

Answer (score 3):

There don't seem to be any Debian repositories that have up-to-date Chromium versions, but there's an Ubuntu Lucid PPA that can be (ab)used.

Add to /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/chromium-daily/ppa/ubuntu lucid main
```

Add the keys for that PPA:

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 4E5E17B5
```

Then just upgrade as usual

Source: http://charlieharvey.org.uk/page/chromium_17_on_squeeze

Comment: It looks like the [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~chromium-daily/+archive/ppa) hasn't been updated since april 2012, though chromium 18 is still much better than chromium 6. The [webapps PPA](https://launchpad.net/~webapps/+archive/preview) could be used, except that it only has the two most recent ubuntu versions.

Comment: This PPA looks usable: https://launchpad.net/~a-v-shkop/+archive/chromium

Comment: I had to use the following command to import the Chromium dev key: 

**sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 4E5E17B5**

Answer (score -2):

A [Debian wiki guide](http://wiki.debian.org/Chromium) says to do the following:

```
aptitude update
aptitude install chromium-browser chromium-browser-l10n
```

Comment: Debian will always lag behind the upstream. The OP is asking how to get the latest.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have Chromium installed (using the way you mentioned) and I want to update it to the latest version available.