# How quickly are Debian security patches moved to "stable"?

Tags: debian, security

Debian is known for its stability. As they require rigorous testing, packages are known to take a long time to become Stable, comparing to other distributions.

In light of the extended review duration, do the security patches of general (non-core) packages have to survive a long wait before entering Stable?

The possibility of the creation of zero-day exploits (by referencing the latest version of a software) during the testing period to compromise an older version in the stable repository seems worrying.

Disregarding the effect of additional software such as SELinux, does the lengthened period impose a security disadvantage, comparing to other distributions?

Comment: What's long to you might be short to someone else; besides, the answer may vary depending on variation situations. Can you narrow your question down considerably?

Answer (score 2):

Security fixes enter Debian stable as soon as possible, given a number of constraints (in particular, coordinated disclosure in some cases, and the time it takes to build updated packages). They don’t undergo the usual unstable → testing → stable migration.

Look at the latest Firefox security update: it was announced by Mozilla [on March 22](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/security/advisories/mfsa2019-09/), and made available in Debian stable [on March 24](https://www.debian.org/security/2019/dsa-4417).

This does mean that there are sometimes regressions, which are fixed in a follow-up update as soon as possible.

See [the Debian security page](https://www.debian.org/security/) for details of the processes and timelines.